Blank rows between rows when creating csv file from SQL table
I'm trying to create a csv file using Flat File Destination from a table in my db. Each time i create it it has a blank row after each row of data. Can anyone suggest why and what I could do to rectify it? Thanks
I've tried Deliminated, Fixed width etc and no matter what I do there's a blank row between each data row.

What is the line delimiter?  Maybe it is set to something that is causing 2 line breaks for each line delimiter?
